# CSS Grid - Set item width on hover

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a simple CSS grid layout that looks like this...

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col1 {
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col2 {
  padding:20px;
  background:green;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col3 {
  padding:20px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col4 {
  padding:20px;
  background:gray;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col1">
    Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    Column 2
  </div>

  <div class="col3">
    Column 3
  </div>

  <div class="col4">
    Column 4
  </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to make it so that when any of the columns are hovered over, they change width so that the hovered column takes up 2fr.

I know with flexbox I can set the width of the item in the item itself, but with grid I set item widths on the container.

Is there a way to set them on the items?

Comment: have you tried : `.container>div:hover {width:40vw}` to checkout how your grid behaves ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834180/8620333 (probably what you are looking for)

Comment: First of all you can use `grid-column: 2` on the hovered element. Now you can switch the *grid item flow direction* to column using `grid-auto-flow: column`; and set the implicit columns to 1fr using `grid-auto-columns: 1fr` - on hover you will have 5 columns now and the *hovered* will take 2fr out of it... see https://jsfiddle.net/anz3e2t5/ (if this is the expected output, will convert to an answer)

Comment: is the expected output the one in the fiddle in the above comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the `grid-column` property. It takes two integers, the starting and ending tracks (e.g. 1/3). The hitch is, you can't expand the last column without some extra work, because it jumps to the next line, out of range of the initial hover zone:

*EDIT:  As per the comment below, I've updated the hover code to be: `grid-column: span 2;` This is the same as "start at your beginning track and span 2 columns." This is a bit cleaner, in that it allows you to set a single style rule for every column. I've also added a :not(.col4) to the rule to avoid the aforementioned issue of the column jumping to the next line. Of course, you need to give each column the same "col" class for this to work:*

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col1 {
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col2 {
  padding:20px;
  background:green;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col3 {
  padding:20px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col4 {
  padding:20px;
  background:gray;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.col:not(.col4):hover{
   grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col1 col">
    Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col2 col">
    Column 2
  </div>

  <div class="col3 col">
    Column 3
  </div>

  <div class="col4 col">
    Column 4
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this has got me thinking that flexbox might be a better fit for my needs

Comment: Actually, it's better to set `grid-column: span 2` on hover then setting fixed column ranges.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I agree, this is a better way! Please see my edit.